# Have view listen to collection event

Tags: backbone.js

I have a view `myView` and a collection `myCollection`. When I `add` a model to `myCollection`, the `add` event is triggered by `myCollection`. How can I have `myView` listen to that `add` event?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass the collection to the view when you instantiate it, and then you can have the view bind to the add event on the collection in the initialize method.

Here's a code example

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.bind('add', this.onModelAdded, this);
  },

  ...other view functions

  onModelAdded: function(addedModel) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

And this is how you pass the collection in when you instantiate the view

```
var view = new MyView({ collection: myCollection });
```

Answer (score 11):

After ver. 0.9.9 (added Dec. 13, 2012) it is recommended to use [listenTO](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo).

In line with this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.onModelAdd);
    },
    onModelAdd: function(model) {
        // do something
    }
});

var myCollection = new MyCollection();
var myView = new MyView({collection: myCollection});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to bind your view to listen on the "add" event of your collection:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.bind('add', this.somethingWasAdded, this)
    },
    somethingWasAdded: function(){

    }
});
new MyView({collection: myCollection})
```