# Realtime Statistics?

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, ember.js

Bit of a 'concept' problem. I've been tasked with creating an internal screen that displays statistics about the company. I thought it would be good to use a frontend framework (between backbone and ember at the moment) BUT the problem is, that I'm pretty limited in terms of what the 'statistics server' can provide so solutions like socket.io are sadly not in the frame. However, I thought about having a very simple API that returns JSON statistics:

```
{
    "Bob":{
        "xs":5,
        "turnover":10000,
        "surveys":5
    }
}
```

Then I could just have the framework poll that API every second or two for changes. But I need to find a way of detecting when a value has changed (so an alert can pop up or something.)

`if(new.value != old.value) alert_function()`

But that would mean doing that for every single figure which could get messy. What would be the best way of doing this kind of thing using either backbone or ember.js?

Answer (score 1):

The [backbone fetch API](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) supports an option {update: true} which will fire collection update events as existing values are merged into the collection. You can then trap those update events and run you custom code. Example from the linked doc:

*For example, to fetch a collection, getting an "add" event for every new model, and a "change" event for every changed existing model, without removing anything:*

```
mycollection.fetch({update: true, remove: false})
```

You can then use [backbone events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) to have your views listen to changes and make updates as needed. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596002/have-view-listen-to-collection-event) has a good example.

Also, this is a bit off-topic, but when I saw your title I immediately thought of [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). It's well-suited to polling a JSON URL and using transitions to update a visualization.